# How to connect to SQL Server with Flutter?

Tags: sql-server, flutter

I have to use SQL Server with Flutter and I don't have another database option because my client has it. I was looking for packages but I only found a package that doesn't run on mobile. Is there any option to do that without web services or api?

Comment: Are you saying your app should connect *directly* to a SQL Server instance *over the Internet*, from a mobile phone? Because that would be an extremely unusual, insecure and inefficient setup. (TDS is a state-based protocol that doesn't do very well with transient clients.) The reason you have trouble finding libraries is that the market for this scenario is vanishingly small. An intermediate web API is your best choice.

Comment: can you install node.js inside the server running the sql server?  then you can access sql server using node.  there are multiple ways that you can connect node with flutter apps, including (1)socket.io, (2) restful api

Answer (score 6):

The first thing that you need to consider is that there is no immediate and extremely effective solution and you have to decide what frameworks and tools to be used. And as mentioned in the comment that the market for this scenario is very small. But there are some ways that you can handle this.

**Remote storage sample solution:**

Here is a basic example of how you should implement this. It was also cited in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63145249/using-sql-server-with-dart):

> [image]
>
> **Client application**
>
> The client application can be any application the user typically uses.
> Some examples:
>
> - Mobile app (written in native, Dart, Xamarin, ...)
> - Desktop app (Electron, WPF, ...)
> - Website app (Angular, React, Vue, ...)
>
> **API**
>
> The API is there to retrieve data, and change data. But It will also
> handle authentication, authorization, logging, doing business logic
>
> **Database**
>
> Your API will then execute queries, inserts, updates, deletes, execute
> stored procedures on the Database of your choice. In your example SQL
> Server.
>
> There are many possibilities on how to set this up, depending on your
> skills, knowledge of frameworks, how you want to deploy things.
>
> How you want to deploy this will limit your choices as well. For your
> API:
>
> - Serverless API (Via Azure Functions, AWS Lambda)
> - Cloud Website (Azure Web Apps)
> - Website hosted on premise
> - Docker container
>
> In real life scenarios this often gets more complex with Firewalls,
> Application Gateways, Virtual networks, clusters.

Answer (score 4):

You can install a SQLServerSocket on your server:

https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket

Install and execute SqlServerSocket.exe in the background on the server machine where SQL Server is installed.

Also, you need a client:

https://github.com/nippur72/SqlServerSocket/tree/master/DartClient

And you can try some connections and queries directly to your DDBB:

```
// creates a connection 
var conn = new 
SqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;Database=mydb;Trusted_connection=yes");

// open connection
await conn.open();

// runs a query returning a single value
var howmany = await conn.queryValue("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers");

// runs a query returning a single row
var myFirstCustomer = await conn.querySingle("SELECT name,age FROM Custormers");
print(myFirstCustomer["name"]);

// runs a query returning all rows
var customers = await conn.query("SELECT TOP 10 name,age FROM Custormers");
for(var customer in customers)
{
   print(customer["name"]);
}

// execute a command, returning the number of rows affected
var n = await conn.execute("UPDATE Customers SET age=0");
print("zeroed $n customers");

// disconnect
await conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation at work, Flutter + sql Server. And I used:

https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn

```
await SqlConn.connect(
  ip: "192.XXXXXXX",
  port: "1433",
  databaseName: "YourDb",
  username: "userDb",
  password: "userPass",
);
```

In example section: https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn/example

you can find the example how to use the package and additional you can copy the code and try to test in your project.

**In addition:** there is no examples with update but it is very easy to use:
write("Update tableHappiness Set Happiness = true where YouFindANewMethod = true");